# Can't correctly pass string as parameter for function

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript, I have created a button with a function that fires when it is clicked. Three parameters are being passed to the function `id`, `clientid`, and `title`. All are strings. Using the first method which can be demonstrated by clicking the Demo1 button, I receive an error of

```
"Expected ')'"
```

Using the second method which can be demonstrated by clicking the Demo2 button, I can successfully fire the function, however the log reads as if it is expecting 5 parameters rather than 3.

```
//console.log(id, clientid, title);
10636,8154,New Opportunity - 1926 Grand Avenue, LLC 5/22/2018 undefined undefined

//console.log(title)
undefined
```

What can I do to properly pass in `title`?

```js
(function() {
  var id = "10636";
  var clientid = "8154";
  var title = "New Opportunity - 1926 Grand Avenue, LLC 5/22/2018";
  console.log('<button style="background-color: #00539B; border: 1px solid #00539B; color: white; border-radius: 4px;" onclick="openAddModal(\'' + id + ',' + clientid + ',' + title + '\')" />' + id + "</button>");
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "<button style='background-color: #00539B; border: 1px solid #00539B; color: white; border-radius: 4px;' onclick=openAddModal(" + id + ',' + clientid + ',' + title + ")>" + 'Demo1' + "</button>"

  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = '<button style="background-color: #00539B; border: 1px solid #00539B; color: white; border-radius: 4px;" onclick="openAddModal(\'' + id + "," + clientid + "," +  title + '\')" />' + 'Demo2' + "</button>"
})();

function openAddModal(id, clientid, title) {
  console.log(id, clientid, title);
  console.log(title);
}
```

```html
<span id="demo1"></span>
<span id="demo2"></span>
```

Comment: don't use the `onclick` attribute of an element; attach a listener after you create the element by using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) (see the section labeled "Example").

Comment: The second button correctly uses `\'`. But you have to wrap _each argument_ in `\'` `\'`. Any reason you resort to `onclick` attributes rather than event listeners?

Comment: @DanO How can I add an Event Listener if I create my button using a `return`? Like: `return "<button style='background-color: #00539B; border: 1px solid #00539B; color: white; border-radius: 4px;' onclick=openAddModal(" + id + ',' + clientid + ',' + title + ")>" + 'Demo1' + "</button>"`